# Can I avoid Exporting LayerClass in Views derived from iPhoneOSGameView?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, opentk

Given a class:

```
public class BaseGameView : OpenTK.Platform.iPhoneOS.iPhoneOSGameView {
```

Constructing `BaseGameView` at runtime will throw **System.Exception: Failed to find selector layerClass**... This is easily resolved by adding the following to the class definition:

```
    [Export ("layerClass")]
    public static new Class GetLayerClass()
    {
        return iPhoneOSGameView.GetLayerClass();
    }
```

This is not so undesirable until I derive another class as follows:

```
public class DerivedGameView : BaseGameView {
```

Constructing the `DerivedGameView` also throws the same exception unless I Export("layerClass") from that class as well.

How can I [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) this out?  I have a handful of these derived views and they all have to have the same snippet of code exporting the layer class... I'd rather not repeat it.

A related question is:
Why is this not necessary for a class simply derived from `UIView`?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently a limitation inside MonoTouch - static methods from base classes aren't exported.

I have filed a bug report for this: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6170 - you can CC yourself on this bug to get notified when it's fixed.

Comment: Thanks for filing the bug! I limited the problem in some of my classes by composing views rather than inheriting. But, the repetition remains in a couple cases. Cheers!